# How to move the files from one bucket to another bucket using cloud function in gcp?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

How can I utilize a Python script within a Google Cloud Function to efficiently transfer files from one GCP bucket to another? The source bucket (let's call it "bucket1") contains a complex directory structure with various folders and subfolders, such as

```
bucket1/folder/subfolder1/file_abc.csv 
bucket2/folder/subfolder2/file_def.csv  
bucket3/folder/subfolder3/file_ghi.csv
```

My goal is to selectively move files that are older than three months to a target bucket ("bucket2"). If a file meets the age condition, I'd like to compress it into a ZIP archive before transferring it to the destination bucket. I've already attempted the code below:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import zipfile
import datetime
import re
import os

def move_files(request, context):
    source_bucket_name = 'bucket1'
    target_bucket_name = 'bucket2'
    
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    source_bucket = storage_client.bucket(source_bucket_name)
    target_bucket = storage_client.bucket(target_bucket_name)

    get_old_date = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=90)).date()

    object_pattern = [re.compile(r'folder/[^/]+/filename.*')]

    all_blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(source_bucket)
    filtered_blobs = [b for b in all_blobs if any(pattern.match(b.name) for pattern in object_pattern)]

    temp_dir = '/tmp/zipped_files'
    os.makedirs(temp_dir, exist_ok=True)

    for blob in filtered_blobs:
        blob_created_time = blob.time_created
        if blob_created_time.date() < get_old_date:
            destination_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, os.path.basename(blob.name))
            blob.download_to_filename(destination_path)

    if os.listdir(temp_dir):
        zip_file_path = '/tmp/zipped_files.zip'
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'w') as zipf:
            for root, _, files in os.walk(temp_dir):
                for file in files:
                    zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file), temp_dir))

        target_blob_name = f'archive_{get_old_date}.zip'
        target_blob = target_bucket.blob(target_blob_name)
        target_blob.upload_from_filename(zip_file_path)

        os.remove(zip_file_path)
        for file in os.listdir(temp_dir):
            os.remove(os.path.join(temp_dir, file))
        os.rmdir(temp_dir)

        print(f'Successfully moved and zipped files to {target_blob_name} in {target_bucket_name} bucket.')
    else:
        print('No files to move and zip.')

    for blob in filtered_blobs:
        blob.delete()

    print("Successful")
```

This code deleting my files from the source bucket but now moving any files to the target bucket. Can someone please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `object\_pattern` you defined to match file names seems to be missing the actual regular expression. Modify it like this:

   ```
   object_pattern = [re.compile(r'folder/[^/]+/file_.*\.csv')]
   ```

   This will match file names like `folder/subfolder1/file\_abc.csv` in the source bucket.
2. In your loop, when downloading files to `destination\_path`, you need to create a ZIP archive before downloading:

   ```
   if blob_created_time.date() < get_old_date:
       destination_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, os.path.basename(blob.name))
       blob.download_to_filename(destination_path)
       with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'a') as zipf:  # Open the existing zip file in 'append' mode and create a new entry in the zip archive
           zipf.write(destination_path, os.path.basename(blob.name)) # Write the downloaded file into the zip archive, using the blob's base name as the file name within the archive
       os.remove(destination_path) # Remove the downloaded file from the temporary location
   ```

   This will add the file to a ZIP archive and remove the original.

References:

- [Streaming a Zip Download from Cloud Functions](https://saturncloud.io/blog/streaming-a-zip-download-from-cloud-functions/)
- [Uploading and Downloading Zip Files in GCP Cloud Storage Using Python](https://dev.to/jakewitcher/uploading-and-downloading-zip-files-in-gcp-cloud-storage-using-python-2l1b)

3. Once the ZIP archive is ready, remember to upload it to the target bucket. Ensure you provide the correct target blob name.